# How to Open an xhtml file in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, xhtml, epub

I'm developing an epub reader. I was able to extract the files from the epub and create a filetree in the device sdcard. However, when I try to read the .xhtml file. It is not working. I tried opening an html file instead and it works.

Here's my code for loading the .xhtml

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new ReaderWebClient());
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/epub/EPUB/cover.xhtml");
```

I just used a hardcoded for the url first as to try if it can load the page.

The webview just displays, **"Webpage not available"**

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: Try creating a `File` object pointing to your file, then use `Uri.fromFile()` to generate a `Uri` to use with `loadUrl()`.

Comment: The Webpage not available message was gone. Though the webview is not displaying anything. Upon checking the log, it says W/AwContents(11558): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.

Comment: Try loading something really simple (a "hello, world" HTML file), to confirm that your `WebView` itself is OK, and that the problem does not lie with your configuration or `ReaderWebClient` or something. Then, start switching over to the real content and see what is in that content that might not work properly.

Comment: I tried using a simple html file and it is ok. It only happens on the xhtml file. I'm not sure if the problem is in the xhtml file itself because it works fine when I tried to open it in my browser application. Are there any possible reasons for the issue?

Comment: Well, without knowing what is in the XHTML file, that is difficult to answer. Make sure that all references (e.g., to images, CSS files, and JavaScript) are relative to the file's own location.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this is I get the data for each item (.xhtml file) and pass it as an argument to `loadDataWithBaseUrl()`. I just have to determine the correct path for the files so that the images and CSS can be loaded correctly.

```
String baseUrl = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/epub" + bookFilename + "/OPS/";
String data = new String(bookReader.book.getContents().get(2).getData());

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, data, "application/xhtml+xml", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "epub/EPUB/cover.xhtml");
```

and take permission for writing to storage in manifest file, like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "epub/EPUB/cover.xhtml");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code .Try it.

```
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        }
        getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
        getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);     
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }   
        loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/epub/EPUB/cover.xhtml");
```

once cross check your file path.